# Show Log out if user logged in.

Tags: php

I have set up a PHP login form within dreamweaver. When dreamweaver inserted the code it worked fine but what I want my head.php file to do is detect if user is logged in. If the user is logged in i want it to Display Logout and If they are not logged in to display login. This is what I have tried..:

```
if ($isValid = true) {
    include 'head/hp1.php';
    ?>
    Login
    <?php
    include 'head/hp2.php';
}
else {
        include 'head/hp1.php';
    ?>
    Logout
    <?php
    include 'head/hp2.php';
}
```

[this](http://bit.ly/1naqwUo) is the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`($isValid = true)`
 is an assignment.

You want to use a comparison operator in a condition: 
`if ($isValid === true)`.

The way you currently have it, the `else` block will never be executed. I would also use more declarative coding habits - what is valid? I would assume a valid session and therefore prompt a logout, which is backwards from your code. This is what I would do:

```
<?php
    include('head/hp1.php');
    echo ($isLoggedIn === true) ? 'Logout' : 'Login';
    include('head/hp2.php');
```

Comment: if ($isValid === true) {
 include 'head/hp1.php';
 ?>
    Logout
    <?php
 include 'head/hp2.php';
}
else {
  include 'head/hp1.php';
 ?>
    Login
    <?php
 include 'head/hp2.php';
} is this right?

Comment: yep, also see my update on how you can make it more DRY

Comment: that didn't work for ne:(. Could you please look at my code to see if I am using the right variable?

Comment: You still have `if ($isValid = true)` in your fiddle. Also, `session_start()` should not be conditional, if the session is set or not, you need `session_start()`.